# iOS Appium keyboard doesn't send commands

Tags: ios, webview, keyboard, appium-ios

I have issue with pressing iOS Keyboard for **Done** or **Return** button. The keyboard doesn't appear at all when I enter information in input fields.

I try to press enter or return with :

`driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);`

I try to enter other commands, but don't work. On Android I used sendKeyCode, but on iOS Appium it seems there is no KeyCode.

Answer (score 0):

Try this whatever you want to sendkeys change as per your requirement

IOSDriver< WebElement> AD= (IOSDriver) driver;
    AD.hideKeyboard("PRESS_KEY", "Done");